# Buenas que condicion usar para traer de 2 bases distintas una datos compleos y otra datos incompletos q traiga los primeros 6 y ult 4 y completatloSql

Tags: sql-server

Tengo 2 bases una completa otra incompleta dw la completa tenggo que fucionarla con la imcompleta pegando todos los numeros tendria que condicionar los primeros 6 y los ultimos 4

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de los datos en cuestión, la consulta que has intentado hacer y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: eh... que?? no se entiende nada de lo que necesitas, es muy confuso tu problema... explica detenidamente mejor tu problema y de paso decinos que intentaste...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.